# How can you add delay to commands in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hello I am new to python and decided to code a simple RPG game using pygame.
The commands work as intended but I need to add a delay to the text being blitted on screen.
If you press the "yes" button, your player is going to attack, if you press the "no" button your player will do nothing and get attacked. After you kill the first boss your player will level up. The text that needs to blitted onto the empty black rectangle is the message congratulating you on levelling up and displays your new stats.
**EDIT: I am not looking for “time.sleep()”. If you could run through my program you’d understand why. I need to add that delay because the intent is to blit a line of text into a black rectangle and to add delay between each line popping up so that it doesn’t happen instantly. If i added a time.sleep() in my function it’s going to pause my TEXT(A, B, C) function for a while and then blit everything at once when I just want it to blit A, B, C with some delay in between.**
The full code is as follows:

```
from pygame import *
#from userInterface import Title, Dead
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
saveState = False

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (30, 30, 30)
FONT = font.SysFont("Courier New", 15)



heroHP = 1000

hero={'name' : 'Hero',
      'height':4,
      'lvl': 1,
      'xp' : 0,
      'reward' : 0,
      'lvlNext':25,
      'stats': {'str' : 12, # strength
                'dex' : 4, # dexterity
                'int' : 15, # intelligence
                'hp'  : heroHP, # health
                'atk' : [250,350]}} # range of attack values


boss1={'name' : 'Imp',
       'xp' : 0,
       'lvlNext':25,
       'reward' : 25,
       'stats': {'hp'  :400,
                'atk' : [300,350]}}


ONE = None
TWO = None
THREE = None
FOUR = None
text = False
counter =0

def TEXT(A, B, C):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, counter, text
    text = True
    if text:
        if counter == 20:
            ONE  = A
        elif counter == 40:
            TWO = B
        elif counter == 60:
            THREE = C
        elif counter == 200:
            ONE = None
            TWO = None
            THREE = None
            FOUR = None
            counter = 0
            text = False
        counter += 1






def level(char): # level up system
    #nStr, nDex, nInt=0,0,0
    while char['xp'] >= char['lvlNext']:
        char['lvl']+=1
        char['xp']=char['xp'] - char['lvlNext']
        char['lvlNext'] = round(char['lvlNext']*1.5)
        nStr=0.5*char['stats']['str']+1
        nDex=0.5*char['stats']['dex']+1
        nInt=0.5*char['stats']['int']+1
        print(f'{char["name"]} levelled up to level {char["lvl"]}!') # current level
        A = (f'{char["name"]} levelled up to level {char["lvl"]}!') # current level

        print(f'( INT {round((char["stats"]["int"] + nInt))} - STR {round(char["stats"]["str"] + nStr)} - DEX {round(char["stats"]["dex"] + nDex)} )') # print new stats
        B = (f'( INT {round((char["stats"]["int"] + nInt))} - STR {round(char["stats"]["str"] + nStr)} - DEX {round(char["stats"]["dex"] + nDex)} )') # print new statsm

        char['stats']['str'] += nStr
        char['stats']['dex'] += nDex
        char['stats']['int'] += nInt

        TEXT(A,B,None)

from random import randint

def takeDmg(attacker, defender): # damage alorithm
    dmg = randint(attacker['stats']['atk'][0], attacker['stats']['atk'][1])
    defender['stats']['hp'] = defender['stats']['hp'] - dmg
    print(f'{defender["name"]} takes {dmg} damage!')
    #TEXT(f'{defender["name"]} takes {dmg} damage!')

    if defender['stats']['hp'] <= 0:
            print(f'{defender["name"]} has been slain...')
            #TEXT(f'{defender["name"]} has been slain...')

            attacker['xp'] += defender['reward']
            level(attacker)
            if defender==hero:
                #Dead()
                pass
            else:
                hero['stats']['hp']=heroHP
                #Title()
                pass


def Battle(player, enemy):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR
    mouse.set_visible(1)
    clock = time.Clock()
    YES = Rect(100, 100, 50, 50)
    NO = Rect(500, 100, 50, 50)
    Text = Rect(70, 300, 500, 75)

    #while ((enemy['stats']['hp']) > 0):
    while True:
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit("Quit") # if X is pressed, exit program
            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()
            elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # 1 is the left mouse button, 2 is middle, 3 is right.
                if e.button == 1:
                    # `event.pos` is the mouse position.
                    if YES.collidepoint(e.pos):
                        takeDmg(player, enemy)
                        print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
                        #TEXT(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')

                        takeDmg(enemy, player)
                    elif NO.collidepoint(e.pos):
                        print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
                        #TEXT(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')

                        takeDmg(enemy, player)


        screen.fill(WHITE)
        draw.rect(screen, BLACK, YES)
        draw.rect(screen, BLACK, NO)
        draw.rect(screen, GRAY, Text)



        YES_surf = FONT.render(("YES"), True, WHITE)
        NO_surf = FONT.render(("NO"), True, WHITE)
        Text1_surf = FONT.render(ONE, True, WHITE)
        Text2_surf = FONT.render(TWO, True, WHITE)
        Text3_surf = FONT.render(THREE, True, WHITE)
        Text4_surf = FONT.render(FOUR, True, WHITE)



        screen.blit(YES_surf, YES)
        screen.blit(NO_surf, NO)
        screen.blit(Text1_surf, (80, 305))
        screen.blit(Text2_surf, (80, 320))
        screen.blit(Text3_surf, (80, 335))
        screen.blit(Text4_surf, (80, 350))





        display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

Battle(hero, boss1)
```

I used the def TEXT(A, B, C) function to add a delay using a counter and then removing the text after a set amount of time. So far I have only implemented the TEXT function when the character levels up to test it but it does not seem to be working.

```
ONE = None
TWO = None
THREE = None
FOUR = None
text = False
counter =0

def TEXT(A, B, C):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, counter, text
    text = True
    if text:
        if counter == 20:
            ONE  = A
        elif counter == 40:
            TWO = B
        elif counter == 60:
            THREE = C
        elif counter == 200:
            ONE = None
            TWO = None
            THREE = None
            FOUR = None
            counter = 0
            text = False
        counter += 1
```

Comment: @JacobIRR I tried that but instead of doing a few seconds per command it accumulated all the delay and blit everything at once. Also doesn’t time.sleep() pause the entire program? I’m having some music playing in the background so pausing the program entirely wouldn’t be such a good idea.

Comment: @JacobIRR Using `time.sleep` will lock the entire thread, making everything unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Using time.sleep is not a good idea to be used on games (this function is intended to be used on a very limited set of cases, real-time apps not being one of them).

Instead, your game should be event-driven based, that means new actions should be spawned when certain conditions are met (game state).

I see you're using pygame, so for time events you should take a look to its module [time](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html), in particular the function [set_timer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) could help you out.

Also, I'd suggest you read this thread [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)